# C++ Initialization query

Tags: c++, initialization

Can someone please tell me if there is anything incorrect with this initialization:

```
static unsigned char* var[1]   
var[0] = new unsigned char[ 800 * 600 ]
```

Is this creating a 2D array at var[0] ? Is this even valid ?

Comment: is the compiler giving any error?

Comment: Hi betabandido, sorry about that. I've edited my post now. Well, this was just some old code I was going through and couldn't understand what was going on. The compiler doesn't give any error.

Comment: Note that the type of `var` and the type of `var[0]` are *not* the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is creating a 1-d array of length (800*600) at var[0]. You'll be able to access its elements with:

```
var[0][0]
var[0][1]
...
var[0][800*600-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

It's creating a single array with 480,000 elements (aka 800*600) and storing it in var[0].  It is not creating a 2D array.  It's valid as long as `var[0]` is an `unsigned char*`.

Comment: Does that mean, it is over-writing var[1], var[2] etc.?

Comment: No -- if `var[0]` is an `unsigned char*` then `var` must be an `unsigned char**` or a `std::vector<unsigned char*>` or some other such type.  Assigning to `var[0]` will not affect `var[1]` or any other element of `var`.

Comment: As `var` only has one element, `var[0]` is all there is!

Comment: @c0d3rz `var[1]` does not exist since your array contains only one element.

Comment: Thanks Edward for the reply. It gives me a lot more understanding. I'm relatively new to C++. Sorry for re-editing the post. I wish I could accept more than one correct answer ...

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your code is not correct, since `var[0]` is not a pointer anymore.</strike>

You may want to do something like:

```
static unsigned char* var;
var = new unsigned char[800 * 600];
```

That does not create a 2D array. It is just a 1D array. Having said that, you can use it as a 2D array if you compute the offset yourself. For instance to access position (row, col) you could do:

```
var[row * 600 + col]
```

If you really want a "true" 2D array, you will need to use for instance:

```
static unsigned char** var;
var = new unsigned char*[600];
for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
    var[i] = new unsigned char[800];
```

Of course, if you do not need to dynamically specify the array size at runtime, you can just use a statically allocated array:

```
static unsigned char var[600][800];
```

BTW, I assume 600 is the number of rows and 800 the number of cols (like in a matrix). That is why I always use 600 in the first index. Otherwise, just swap the values.

Comment: `var[0]` is of type `unsigned char*`.

Comment: @K-ballo the OP changed the code. Before it was just `unsigned char* var;`

Comment: Or you could do `unsigned char var[600][800];` and save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: @BoPersson That's true, but I guess the OP would not use dynamic allocation if his/her problem could be solved with a statically allocated array.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something more like (although I may be interrupting the question wrong);

```
static unsigned char* var = new char*[800]

for (int i =0; i < 800; i++)
     var[i] = new char[600]
```

That will give you a 800x600 2d character array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite incorrect to use `new[]`. What you're looking for is `std::vector<unsigned int> var(800 * 600);`.